# How is my textbook using this point slope equation of a line?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I'm learning about Newton's Method via this text:

[image]

How is the point slope method being used? Why are we subbing $x_2$ and 0 in the wrong places in this equation:

$$0 - f(x_1) = f'(x_1)(x_2 - x_1)$$

Is the author just subbing in a point for the point-slope equation of a line? Because from what I see, the point slope form of a line uses the slope and plugs in the given point in the 2nd positions:

https://www.mathsisfun.com/algebra/line-equation-point-slope.html

Comment: Why do you think they are being subbed in the wrong place?  $y- f(x_1) = f'(x_1) (x - x_1)$.  And we have a point.  $(x_2, 0)$ so $y = 0$ and $x = x_2$ so..... 0 - f(x_1) = f'(x_1)(x_2 - x_2)$ is the *correct* placing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $(x_a, y_a) $ and a point on a line and the slope is $m$ the line formula is

$y - y_a = m(x - x_a)$.

So here $m = f'(x_1)$ and $(x_1, f(x_1))$ is one point on the line so

$y - f(x_1) = f'(x_1)(x - x_1)$

is the equation of the line.

So if  $(w, v)$ is a point  on the line, it's satisfy the equation we'd get if we plugged in $y = v$ and $x = w$ and get

$v - f(x_1) = f'(x_1)(w - x_1)$

Now we want to plug in  the $x$ intercept $(x_2, 0)$.

So $y = 0$ and $x = x_2$  and we plug them in:

So $0 - f(x_1) = f'(x_1)(x_2 - x_1)$.

Answer (score 3):

The slope at the point $x_1$ is

$$
f'(x_1) = \left.\frac{{\rm d}f}{{\rm d}x}\right|_{x=x_1}
$$

that means that the equation of the line with slope $f'(x_1)$ going through the point $(x_1, y_1)$ is

$$
y - y_1 = f'(x_1)(x-x_1)
$$

You also want to find the point $x_2$ that makes $y=0$. Substituting this constraint in the equation above you get

$$
0-y_1 = f'(x_1)(x_2 - x_1)
$$

or equivalently

$$
x_2 = x_1 - \frac{y_1}{f'(x_1)}
$$

Answer (score 3):

Note that to find the $x$-intercept we let $y=0$

The equation $$0 - f(x_1) = f'(x_1)(x_2 - x_1)$$ is result of replacing $y$ with $0$ in order to find the x-intercept of the tangent line.

They replaced $ y$ with  $0$ and solved for $ x_2$.